# Delete all users when they don't update profile_fields

Tags: wp-cron

1. I create a profile_fields named name, when users sign up for an account they will receive an email containing the nickname.
2. When the user logs in, there will be a page to enter profile_fields (name), if profile_fields = nickname (from email), they will be redirected to the main edit page.

(1,2 I did it).

I want users who can't update profile_fields (name) for a day, to be permanently deleted.
Is there any way to make this work? please, i have searched many places but to no avail
I found a code and corrected it but I don't know if it's wrong???

````
function my_clearOldUsers() {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE datediff(now(), user_registered) > 1");
    if ($oldUsers = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N)) {
        foreach ($oldUsers as $user_id) {
            $nickname = $user->user_login
            $xacminh = get_user_meta( $user_id[0], 'name', true );
            if($xacminh != $nickname) {
            wp_delete_user($user_id[0]); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
add_action('my_dailyClearOut', 'my_clearOldUsers');  ```
````

Comment: At a glance that code looks like it should work to delete users more than a day old where their `name` usermeta doesn't equal their login. But you also need to set up a cron job that creates the `my_dailyClearOut` action's schedule - your current code doesn't actually set a schedule up to call the function.

Comment: this is extremely similar to an existing question asked several days ago at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/403390/auto-delete-users-auto-delete-users/403391#403391, you should look at my answer there

Comment: sorry I forgot to include the default Wordpress cron.
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_dailyClearOut');
I did the same as above and waited for a day but the user still didn't disappear